# How to alias a table name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Since upgrading to Rails 5 I have a query that is not working. It is unable to get results from a table by its alias. The error is that "from" takes zero arguments now. The version of arel is 9.0, the version of Rails is 5.2.4.3

```
      offers = Offer.arel_table
      o2 = offers.alias("o2")

      seen_offers = offers.from("offers as o2").project(o2[:merchant_id], o2[:display_name])
```

this is the error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Arel::Table#from`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel%2FTable:from) takes 0 arguments because it generates a `SelectManager`:

```
SelectManager.new(self)
```

What you are looking for is [`SelectManager#from`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel%2FSelectManager:from) and the issue is easily correctable (just switch the `project` and the `from`)

```
offers.project(o2[:merchant_id], o2[:display_name]).from(o2)
```

`project` will return a `SelectManager` and then `from` will simply change the source